# Pandas, normalising json-per-line

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has the `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` method that can flatten json.

I've got a source file that contains json-per-line data (streamed to the file by a long running process).  I'm not really in a position to modify what is written to that file.  Here's a contrived example of JSON:

`{"type": "bar", "aspect": {"Positive": 1, "Negative": 0.6}}
 {"type": "bar", "aspect": {"Positive": 0.6, "Negative": 1.5}}`

I can read it in using the normal `pandas.read_json` method by passing the `lines=True` parameter.  However I'd like it to be flattened, as if by json_normalize, as that gets it in to a really useful form e.g.

`>>> json_normalize(json.loads('{"type": "bar", "aspect": {"Positive": 1, "Negative": 0.6}}'))
   aspect.Negative  aspect.Positive type
0              0.6                1  bar`

If I loop through the source, normalize and append, that's going to result in a full copy for each line I add.  That's going to really hurt performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) + `DataFrame constructor` + [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) + [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines = True)
print (df)
                                              aspect type
0    {'Negative': 0.6000000000000001, 'Positive': 1}  bar
1  {'Negative': 1.5, 'Positive': 0.6000000000000001}  bar

df = (pd.DataFrame(df['aspect'].values.tolist())
        .add_prefix('aspect.')
        .join(df.drop('aspect', 1)))
print (df)
   aspect.Negative  aspect.Positive type
0              0.6              1.0  bar
1              1.5              0.6  bar
```

Or for each row call `json.loads` and last use `json_normalize`:

```
df = json_normalize(pd.Series(open('file.json').readlines()).apply(json.loads))
print (df)
   aspect.Negative  aspect.Positive type
0              0.6              1.0  bar
1              1.5              0.6  bar
```

---

```
df = json_normalize([json.loads(x) for x in open('file.json').readlines()])
print (df)

   aspect.Negative  aspect.Positive type
0              0.6              1.0  bar
1              1.5              0.6  bar
```

**Timings** in 5k rows:

```
In [13]: %timeit json_normalize([json.loads(x) for x in open('file.json').readlines()])
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit json_normalize(pd.Series(open('file.json').readlines()).apply(json.loads))
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines = True)
    ...: df = (pd.DataFrame(df['aspect'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('aspect.').join(df.drop('aspect', 1)))
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 30.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much for including the timeit information!

Comment: Glad can help! I was curious too which solution is fastest ;)

Comment: @jezrael Very helpful answer. Thank you.